# Does enumeration imply equinumerosity (one-to-one correspondence)?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I know that the definition of denumerability states that a set $A$ is denumerable IFF there exists a one-to-one correspondence of $A$ with the set of Natural Numbers, i.e. $A$ and $\mathbb N$ are equinumerous. In Cantor's proof of the Non-countability of the Continuum, he showed that the set of real numbers in $(0,1)$ cannot be enumerated and therefore denumerable. So does this mean that if I can enumerate a set, it automatically implies the existence of a one-to-one correspondence with $\mathbb N$?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, just think about what you do when you enumerate the set..

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a set $A = \{a_1, a_2, a_3. \dots \}$. Then you can always have the function $f: A\to \Bbb{N}$ where $f(a_n)=n$. What can be said about $f$?

Answer (score 0):

In the context of set theory, enumerating a set means it is denumerable, and if a set is denumerable then it can be enumerated.

In some other contexts, like computability and recursion theory, the term "enumerable set" usually means "recursively enumerable" which means that the function which enumerates is recursive. This also means that the set is a subset of $\Bbb N$, or some other fixed countable set, and not an arbitrary set.

Finally, Cantor showed that $\Bbb R$ is **not** denumerable.